# Jenkins AWS code deployment error from local machine

Tags: aws-code-deploy

I am trying to deploy an application to AWS code deploy. I have created a Jenkins job to build my angular 8 application, build them using jenkins that run on windows local machine which is at my home (not an EC2 instance). After dist file has got generated, Code deployment step is triggered. But, it throws error saying as below:

```
21:47:40 
21:47:40 > tihlc@0.0.0 copy C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\tihlc
21:47:40 > copy app.js dist\tihlc && copy auth.js dist\tihlc && copy package.json dist\tihlc && copy appspec.yml dist\tihlc && mkdir dist\tihlc\scripts && copy scripts\* dist\tihlc\scripts\
21:47:40 
21:47:40         1 file(s) copied.
21:47:40         1 file(s) copied.
21:47:40         1 file(s) copied.
21:47:40         1 file(s) copied.
21:47:40         5 file(s) copied.
21:47:40 
21:47:40 C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\tihlc>exit 0 
21:47:41 Failed CodeDeploy post-build step; exception follows.
21:47:41 Cannot find application named 'Tihlc-CodeDeployment'
21:47:41 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find application named 'Tihlc-CodeDeployment'
21:47:41    at com.amazonaws.codedeploy.AWSCodeDeployPublisher.verifyCodeDeployApplication(AWSCodeDeployPublisher.java:288)
21:47:41    at com.amazonaws.codedeploy.AWSCodeDeployPublisher.perform(AWSCodeDeployPublisher.java:226)
21:47:41    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:78)
21:47:41    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
21:47:41    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
21:47:41    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
21:47:41    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
21:47:41    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
21:47:41    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1881)
21:47:41    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
21:47:41    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
21:47:41    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
21:47:41 ERROR: Step ‘Deploy an application to AWS CodeDeploy’ failed: null
21:47:41 Finished: FAILURE
```

I have configured IAM user with code deploy access and S3 access too and added respective access Key and Secret key as credentials in Jenkins. I have set up the deployment by following this [link](https://www.cuelogic.com/blog/how-to-use-jenkins-and-aws-code-deploy-as-a-ci-cd-tool) and [link2](https://medium.com/faun/create-a-continuous-delivery-pipeline-using-jenkins-gitlab-github-and-deploy-on-aws-ec2-with-3aaadf073196)

I was hoping it should work fine. But now I am clueless about what was I missing. Was this plugin in Jenkins designed to work for the one hosted only in ec2 instance?

pardon me for my sentence formation being awkward.

Answer (score 1):

> 21:47:41 Cannot find application named 'Tihlc-CodeDeployment'

This suggests that the Plugin is looking for the CodeDeploy application in the wrong region. Please check the configuration of the plugin if there is a region somewhere and please correct it to the region where you have created the CodeDeploy application (the default example is for ap-northeast-1 which may not be your case).

Comment: As far as the region is concerned I have kept it as ap-south-1. Don't think that's the issue